# How do I use ESC/POS commands to enable slip printing mode for an Epson TM-H6000III?

Tags: printing, epson, escpos

I've got an Epson TM-H6000III printer and I'm developing an application that needs to print on the front of entrance badges for people. I've been toying with it for several days now and have learned all the fun secrets. However, the one critical thing that eludes me is how to activate the slip printing feature. Originally I was going to develop my application on Android, however, while Epson's Android driver works wonders and the slip printing worked - there were other issues with using Android, so I switch to using plain old Java and Swing.

Problem is I can't seem to replicate the Android example results by just sending raw ESC/POS commands to the printer. I know my commands are working because the print is executing all the other commands just fine. So I think it's my lack of finding proper documentation on ESC/POS for this printer. What documentation I can find severely lacks mentioning my printer model and when I think I'm on a lead, it goes no place.

I found these documents that I felt were most relevant:

1. http://cdn.posguys.com/download/TM-H6000III/tmh6000iii_trg_revb.pdf
2. http://content.epson.de/fileadmin/content/files/RSD/AnwenderhandPDFs/DE/TM-930II_user_e.pdf
3. https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/pos/bulk/tm-h6000iv_eng_trg_reva_00.pdf
4. http://download.delfi.com/SupportDL/Epson/Manuals/TM-T88IV/Programming%20manual%20APG_1005_receipt.pdf

The first document mentions potential commands but gives no examples. Second says to use `ESC c0 n`, again no example and it's for an older printer. Third also mentions useful commands on page 74 but also no examples or even codes for that matter. And the last one has probably been the most helpful as it includes examples but it doesn't mention slip printing, I think it's because none of the models' listed support such a feature.

I've grown desperate enough that I even tried enabling the hexadecimal dump on the same printers at my work to see if they give me a clue and I only found how to start reading the MICR - not super useful. `FS a 30 00` Plus because the printer give no status messages in that mode (kind of defeats the purpose of that feature) the POS would freeze. So likely no chance of me even seeing the code. :(

Could someone please point me to a model-specific detailed ESC/POS manual or give me an example of commands? I can't find anything out from the Android examples, besides maybe some hints.

I would greatly appreciate it, I need to deliver a working prototype in two weeks and I'm getting down to the wire.

Comment: This document will be helpful. [EPSON Paper Roll/Cut Sheet Printers ESC/POS Application Programming Guide](ftp://ftp.bisart.eu/PrintTrade/servis/APG_1004_roll_cut.pdf)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for the same feature. The question is from a while ago but for anyone else looking for a solution this might help. It seems that the `ESC c0` command is actually the way to go. I will have to actually try this once the printer arrives but the instructions in the link (see below) look solid.

According to this [Github-Issue](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos/issues/18) (look further down, last longer comment) the code for selecting the dot matrix printer is `ESC c0 4` (Hex: `1B 63 30 04`) and for setting it back to the 80mm roll `ESC c0 3` (Hex: `1B 63 30 03`).

Pretty obscure though, I could not find any ESC/POS reference manual that actually listed the `ESC c0` command, only `ESC c3` to `c5`. Maybe there are not many POS printers that actually feature two (or three) types of printers.

The only other command that was vaguely related was `ESC =` (`1B 3D`) which lets you select a 'peripheral device'. Depending on which reference manual you check the numbers could be

- `1` and `2` (Display module **off** or **on**), [EPSON Reference](https://www.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=191)

or for example

- `0` and `1` (Printer **off** or **on**), [Star Micronics Reference PDF - page 54](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/mannualfolder/escpos_cm_en.pdf), and any number up to 255